# Change or Update Google Map marker in a second fragment on location update from first fragment in a pageviewer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, android-maps

i am new to android (2weeks old), i am having difficulties updating google map marker on fragment in pager viewer

After getting user longitude and latitude when photo is taken with camera from first fragment, i want to update marker or if possible recreate map with new marker on google map in second fragment.

After using interface to transfer data from fragment1(ImageFragment) to fragment2(MapFragment), i still cant update the map, i am having error on this line and anything relate to GoogleMap

```
googleMap.addMarker(marker);// null pointer exeception here  

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(15).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));// and null pointer exeception here  too
```

i still get nullpointer exception error on this line below. // adding marker googleMap.addMarker(marker); this is my logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.solexadex.itrak.i_trak.MapFragment.displayMapOnFragment(‌​MapFragment.java:101‌​)
```

These are my code: MapFragment Class

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements ImageFragment.DisplayMapOnFragment {
//-------------- class variables
private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private FragmentActivity myContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
            false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 7.385044;
    double longitude = 9.486671;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    // Perform any camera updates here
    return v;
}


@Override
public void displayMapOnFragment(double latitude, double longitude) {


    //initilizeMap();


    // latitude and longitude
    // double latitude = 9.155543;
    //double longitude = 7.321151;//9.155543, 7.321151

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    //googleMap.
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}}
```

And ImageFragment Class below

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {



private  Context mContext;
double longitude, latitude;
public String street,city, state, country,zip,knownName,iDate;

private  final Context dialogContext = getActivity();


    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
    FloatingActionButton button;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image,
                container, false);
        mContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        button = ( FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // now access the TextView as you want
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                // convert byte array to Bitmap

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                        byteArray.length);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //call
              this.getCoord();
            }
        }
    }


public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(double uLat, double uLong);
}
public interface OnDataPass2 {
    public void onDatapass2(String address, String city, String state, String postalCode, String KnowName, String createdDate);
}

public interface DisplayMapOnFragment {
    public void displayMapOnFragment(double mapLat, double mapLong);
}


OnDataPass dataPasser;
OnDataPass2 dataPasser2;
DisplayMapOnFragment displayMapOnFragment;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    try {
        displayMapOnFragment = (DisplayMapOnFragment) a;
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
        dataPasser2 = (OnDataPass2) a;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(a.toString()
                + " must implement OnDataPass");
    }
}


public void passData(double uLong, double uLat) {
    dataPasser.onDataPass(uLong, uLat);
}

int aCount=20; //initialize counter to loop getCoord method if 0.0 is returned so as to ge value that is not 0.0
public void getCoord()
{
    MapFragment mf = new MapFragment();

    NewTrackActivity newTrackActivity=new NewTrackActivity();

    TrackGPS gps = new TrackGPS(mContext);
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        latitude  = gps.getLatitude();
        if(aCount!=20)
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Retrying to get Coordinate: "+aCount+"\nLongitude:"+Double.toString(longitude)+"\nLatitude:"+Double.toString(latitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            //Log.e("latitude", "inside latitude--" + latitude);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                 street = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                iDate=dateFormat.format(date);

               // locationTxt.setText(address + " " + city + " " + country);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        newTrackActivity.onDataPass( longitude, latitude);
        newTrackActivity.onDatapass2( street, city, state, zip, knownName, iDate);

        if(Double.compare(latitude,0.00)==0 && aCount>0) {
            aCount--;
            getCoord();
        }
        if(aCount<=1) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Please retake photo to get current position coordinate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            aCount=20; //reset count
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Coordinates found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        newTrackActivity.displayMapOnFragment(latitude, longitude);
        // Supply value
     //   Bundle args = new Bundle();
       // args.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
        //args.putDouble("longitude", longitude);
        //mf.setArguments(args);

    }
    else
    {
        gps.showSettingsAlert(mContext);
    }


}
}
```

Fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Once you have the lat/lon in the Activity, just pass it to the Google Map Fragment through a public method defined in the Fragment.  Take a look at both of the linked duplicates for more info.

Comment: @DanielNugent, thanks for the prompt response, from the first fragment, i have gotten the lat/lon, i also have a method created in the fragment2 and i called it from fragment1 after getting the lat/lon. but getting nullpointer exception on addMarker. please will appreciate if you can break it down a little for me to understand and implement. thank you.

Comment: After using the interface feedback from the link provided, i still get nullpointer exception error on this line below. 
        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

this is my logcat

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at com.solexadex.itrak.i_trak.MapFragment.displayMapOnFragment(MapFragment.java:101)

Comment: Edit your question and explain exactly what your issue is, and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) If you can provide a good MCVE, I'll re-open your question.

Comment: I've re-opened the question, but there is still not enough info.  Try to add enough info that someone can plug your code into a project and reproduce the issue.  If you can do that, someone will surely be able to provide an answer.